# Loop each column and match the value then create another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as below:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.date_range(start='2016-03-10', end='2019-03-10'),
                 'a': [0 for _ in range(1096)],
                  'b': [0 for _ in range(1096)]})
indices_a = [0,1,3,6,10,15, 20, 40, 50,70, 100,400,700]
indices_b = [0,1,3,6,10,15, 20, 40, 50,70, 100,400,700]

a.loc[indices_a,'a'] = 1
a.loc[indices_b,'b'] = 1
```

Above will create a dataframe with some indexes for a and b to be 0 and 1.

What I want to do is use pandas library functions to loop each column and find if the value is 1 then create another dataframe as below example

## The date below is just an example which represents the index with value 1 and category as the column name. so the below is not correct but just to give an idea of my input

```
time | category
2018-03-10 | a
2018-02-10 | a
2018-04-10 | a
2018-05-10 | a
2018-06-10 | b
2018-07-10 | b
2018-08-10 | b
2018-09-10 | b
2018-10-10 | b
```

My attempts:

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
for col in a.columns[1:]:
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'category': [col for _ in range(len(a[a[col]==1]))],
                            'time':a[a[col]==1]['time'].values})
    output = output.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
# Although my attemp produced correct output but its just not the dataframe or pandas way of doing things. Since I wish to know more pandas way of handling the dataframe, please kindly use the pandas functions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need `melt` and `.query`

```
b = a.melt(id_vars='time',var_name='category').query('value == 1')\
                                              .drop('value',axis=1)

print(b)

           time category
0    2016-03-10        a
1    2016-03-11        a
3    2016-03-13        a
6    2016-03-16        a
10   2016-03-20        a
15   2016-03-25        a
20   2016-03-30        a
40   2016-04-19        a
50   2016-04-29        a
70   2016-05-19        a
100  2016-06-18        a
400  2017-04-14        a
700  2018-02-08        a
1096 2016-03-10        b
1097 2016-03-11        b
1099 2016-03-13        b
1102 2016-03-16        b
1106 2016-03-20        b
1111 2016-03-25        b
1116 2016-03-30        b
1136 2016-04-19        b
1146 2016-04-29        b
1166 2016-05-19        b
1196 2016-06-18        b
1496 2017-04-14        b
1796 2018-02-08        b
```

Comment: and also `var_name='category'`